# Pandas is importing a column with square brackets as a string instead of list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Using `pd.read_csv` I am importing a dataframe. One of the columns contains lists of strings. For example:

```
>>> df['topic'].head(5)
0    ['ECONOMIC PERFORMANCE', 'ECONOMICS', 'EQUITY ...
1    ['CAPACITY/FACILITIES', 'CORPORATE/INDUSTRIAL']
2    ['PERFORMANCE', 'ACCOUNTS/EARNINGS', 'CORPORAT...
3    ['PERFORMANCE', 'ACCOUNTS/EARNINGS', 'CORPORAT...
4    ['STRATEGY/PLANS', 'NEW PRODUCTS/SERVICES', 'C...
Name: topic, dtype: object
```

Though this column should be full of lists, pandas is importing it as strings. How can I get pandas to import this as a column of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the column with strings to Python lists with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). For example:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df["topic"] = df["topic"].apply(literal_eval)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                         topic
0    [ECONOMIC PERFORMANCE, ECONOMICS, EQUITY]
1  [CAPACITY/FACILITIES, CORPORATE/INDUSTRIAL]
2  [PERFORMANCE, ACCOUNTS/EARNINGS, CORPORATE]
3  [PERFORMANCE, ACCOUNTS/EARNINGS, CORPORATE]
4      [STRATEGY/PLANS, NEW PRODUCTS/SERVICES]
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to use apply, as this is a large list. But I think if all else fails, that will work well.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely Does this mean that the built-in Python `eval()` does not work?  And if not why?

Comment: @jch `eval()` will work also, but is not considered safe - it can execute arbitrary code, but `ast.literal_eval` will parse only literal structures such as integers, strings, lists...